# I want to be sure if there is at least one 'G' between every '$' and 'T'

Tags: c

I want to write a Function with 1 argument, a string of characters [including $ (money), T (thief), G (guard)] and check if there is at least 1 guard (G) between every T (thief) and $ (money).

Here is my Code but it doesn't work fine for some Inputs

```
int Casino_Security (char* casino)
{

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (*(casino + i))
    {
        if(casino[i] == 'T' || casino[i] == '$')
            for(j=i+1; j<=strlen(casino) || casino[j] == 'G'; j++)
                if(casino[j] == 'T' || casino[j] == '$') 
                    if(casino[i] != casino[j])
                        return 0;
        i++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please give some inputs that don't work. More importantly have you actually attempted to debug the code? Best way is to run the program in a debugger and step thru it line by line. If you have, what did you find, where do things go wrong?

Comment: Input: H$FGT . The Function should return 1 but it returns 0! I tested it just now. I can write the function in way to check '$' and 'T' separately, but I want use only one if statement and check both T and $

Comment: Please [edit] your question with new information. Here in the comments it will get lost. -- You might want to take the [tour] and to read "[ask]".

Answer (score 0):

In the inner `for`loop, the continuation test should be `j<=strlen(casino) && casino[j] != 'G';` : it means breaking the loop as soon as there's a guard.